# Magento - Admin/Backend has wrong currency separator

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, backend, currency, magento2.4.5p1

we are using the Magento 2.4.5-p1 version.
On frontend we have the correct currency separator for Germany. eg. 149,99 €.
But on admin/backend we have on price input field 149.99.
Any idea, how to change this? Its a small issue, but sometimes on editing products its annoying.